# Data-pulling fuctions

Tags: python, mysql

The first function, `sqlPull()`, connects to a local MySQL database and pulls the last 20 rows from the database every 5 seconds.  The data coming in is a list of tuples, where `MAC`, `RSSI` and `TimeStamp` are the 3 elements in each tuple.  The data is entering the database at a variable rate, where sometimes I'll have tons of entries in a minute and sometimes I will have very few.  The data that is coming in consists of a MAC address, an `RSSI` and a `TimeStamp` for every time a user's device pings our hardware.  So, we will have unique MAC addresses that will have changing `RSSIs` and `TimeStamps` over a period of time.

Since I never know how many database entries will be added within the 5 seconds that the first function runs on, the second function, `dupCatch()` is used to detect and eliminate duplicates.

The third function, `post()`, just sends a POST request to Google Analytics with the data stripped of duplicates.

Here is how I would like to optimize my code:

My next step in this process is to calculate the length of time between a users first and last entries in the database.  We can assume that the max time between a user's entry and exit is 2 hours (in this time, the users would probably have 10-15 pings with different `RSSI`s and timestamps).  I have been trying to think of the best way to do this with the current code, but everything I am thinking of seems so unwieldy.  In my mind, `sqlPull()` and/or `dupCatch()` could be rewritten/optimized to better serve my purposes for a function to calculate length of time between entry and exit.

How would you pull data that is coming in at a variable and unpredictable rate?

```
import mysql.connector
import datetime
import requests
import time

run = True 

def sqlPull():
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(user='XXXXX', password='XXXXX', host='XXXXX', database='XXXXX')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT TimeStamp, MAC, RSSI FROM wifiscan ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC LIMIT 20;")
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    connection.close()
    time.sleep(5)
    return data

seen = set()
def dupCatch():
    data = sqlPull()
    new_data = []
    for (TimeStamp, MAC, RSSI) in data:
        if (TimeStamp, MAC, RSSI) not in seen:
            seen.add((TimeStamp, MAC, RSSI))
            new_data.append((TimeStamp, MAC, RSSI))  
    print new_data
    return new_data

def post():
    new_data = dupCatch()
    for ((TimeStamp, MAC, RSSI)) in new_data:
        payload = {'v':'1','tid':'XXXXXX','cid': '1','t':'event', 'ec': MAC, 'ea': 'InStore', 'el': RSSI}
        requests.post("http://www.google-analytics.com/collect", data = payload)


while run is True:
    post()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need rate-limit the amount of records you receive. You'll have to determine what the best rate is by yourself, as that is specific to your scenario.

### High Priority:

- Keep the list of "synced" entries in the database. Something like an `IsSentToAnalytics` column.
- After you process a batch, update the database records you just selected with the synced set to yes, or 1, or true. The simplest way to do this would be to update each entry one by one, but there are more efficient solutions to that out there.
- Your database query should only select from items that are not yet synced. This will be lighter on the database. (i.e. add the predicate `and where IsSentToAnalytics <> 1`)
- Your `dupCheck` is catering for the above flag, essentially you're pulling unused data every time if it's a quiet period hence why you need the `dupCheck`. And also, MISSING data if it's a busy period. That can happen if you got more than 20 entries added to your database since your last run. This may be fine for hobby projects, but shoddy for production deployments.
- Please, please add a surrogate primary key to your database. If anything, it keeps you from having to generate a hash every time you want to do a `dupCheck`.
- The above entry kind of depends on how you generate the data. But since you have timestamp in there, I'm assuming every single record is unique anyways, so you might as well use the surrogate key as suggested. By the way, the surrogate key will be a sequence used as a primary key. Every entry inserted gets a unique value.
- Edit. From your feedback below, you say you sometimes have duplicate values for the same timestamp. If that's the case, then you need to filter them out before inserting into the database initially. Whatever job/service that creates those entries needs to filter out the duplicates. You can try insert, and catch the DBException because it will fail the column constraint. Or, you could first do a select, and if no result is returned, insert, otherwise discard. You'll need to edit your question with more info for us to give you more detail on that.

### Low Priority:

- Move your sleep method into your while loop, not in your SQL pull, please. There is no need to sleep before returning data. Put the sleep where it belongs. Either that or change your function to be called `PullDataAndSleep`. If you think that function name is fine, then don't change the code inside it, just rename. Otherwise, put the sleep elsewhere.
- Reuse your connection. You are disconnecting and reconnecting to the database every 5 seconds, it's pointless unless you expect your database connection to drop.
- Change your while loop to just be "while Run", that's like saying `while var == True`. You're basically saying if `True == True`, then run. It's redundant.
- Pull from the database at constant intervals(you are using 5s, play around with it).
- Enforce an upper-bound amount of returned entries (you have 20)
- The last two entries above will help you rate-limit how many requests you send off to Google. If you spam them too quickly, they might block/ban your IP.

Comment: That point-form list could use some formatting & prioritization :)

Comment: @retailcoder Added some formatting and separated into two priorities. Can't help that I think in lists :)

Comment: No problem - thanks for [contributing](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/999/call-of-duty-were-on-a-mission?cb=1)!

Comment: @ZoranPavlovic Hi thanks you for your detailed response.  I have one question before I dive into this (90% of which i do not understand).  You say " But since you have timestamp in there, I'm assuming every single record is unique anyways."  This is actually not true - Every once in a while i get multiple entries with the same timestamp.  Knowing this, would you change anything about your post? Thanks!

Comment: @user1887261 Not really... Since you have the dupCheck on the consuming side it means that you don't need those duplicates. So you can just throw them away. I'll add how  as another point in the high-priority list just now.

Answer (score 0):

### Optimal Querying

I would try to arrange things such that you don't have to don't have to worry about duplicate records.

In your query you can pull only records that have a time stamp at least one second prior to the current database time. You will similarly only pull records that are greater than or equal to the server time during the last pull.

You will need a way to track that last/next query time in the event the system stops running and you have to restart it. Be sure your solution will never query the same data twice or exclude any particular second.

### Exit Detection

It sounds like you'll want the exit detection to provide a different type of response. I doubt you'll be able to reuse the pull code.

For efficiency you can have the database query all records within the last couple of hours, group by MAC, giving maximum time found, minimum time found and perhaps the number of records involved for each MAC.

Maybe go with something like pullRecent and pullSessions.

### Notes

I agree with Zoran, there is no point in putting a delay in the query function. That logic should probably reside in your while loop.

For recovery purposes you could use a single row table that tracks the highest last or the next second to query from.

If you wanted to make your polling responsive to changing usage levels then consider having a counter in the tracking table (or a separate memory based table) that is updated during addition of wifiscan records. Perform a poll run whenever N records are added or M minutes passes. Rest the counter during each poll event.

Session calculation efforts could also be managed with the help of a tracking table. However, I suspect you will need a way to "extend" sessions that continue to be active after you've already found an earlier start and end time. If you need to find a continuous period of non-use to find session boundaries than the two hour grouped query I suggested won't suffice.